# QGIS layout composer always loads small, zoomed-out page

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts

QGIS 3.22.8 (but has occurred in previous versions too).

I have a couple of Layout templates saved to my project. Each time I open one, they appear small like so:

[image]

For sure, I can press this 'Zoom Full' button to fit the page to screen:

[image]

but how can I prevent this annoying default behaviour? Even if I fix (click 'Zoom Full', save project, exit QGIS, then reload the QGIS file), the issue remains.

QGIS .qgz project file containing layout tamplate can be downloaded from: https://we.tl/t-rrnJlMYksC

Comment: If you press the button to fit the page to screen, save the project, close and reopen: does the problem persist?

Comment: @Babel yes. I tried to say this in the last sentence of my question. I'll clarify the OP.

Comment: Did the layout originally have a much larger page dimension which was reduced to the current one, as if the original setting is being remembered?  If you fix things and then duplicate the layout does the duplicate also show the same behavior?  What about saving to a new project?

Comment: did you check if there is a graphic element, which is placed outside your page?

Comment: @eurojam there is no graphic outside the page area. Outside elements would be captured when the 'Zoom full' button is clicked anyway.

Comment: @John the original layout would have been the default, blank QGIS layout from a fresh installation. I fixed the zoom, duplicated the layout, saved the project as a new project file, quit, then opened the new project... the issue remains.

Comment: Can you share the project + data? Otherwise, we just continue to speculate and guess...

Comment: @Babel have shared a link in OP.

Comment: I experienced the same issue. I don't have a solution, just confirming that it's not a one-off. Since updating to 3.28 it appears not to happen anymore.

Comment: Does this happen with all your projects or only this one or derivations of this one?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same behaviour as you describe it with the project file you provided, even though the page is not so small as in your case (see screenshot). A quick workaround is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to zoom full.

[image]

Comment: what QGIS version are you using? Thanks for looking

Comment: QGIS 3.28.0-Firenze. Not sure if it (also) depends on screen resolution?

Comment: I don't think so, as the issue looks the same when run on my laptop monitor or when opened on a bigger external monitor.